# Richfaces 4: Rendering issue for mixed client / ajax fall-back validation

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf, client-side-validation

I use mixed client-side validation (CSV) with JSR-303 bean validation constraints and ajax-fallback validation for an h:inputText tag.

But if the CSV passes and the ajax fall-back validation fails this results in flickering validation messages. I assume this is because first the client side removes the message and the later ajax call adds the message again. This is in particular annoying if the validation is triggered by `<rich:validator event="keyup" />.`

If only one type of validation is implemented, then the message is displayed nicely without flickering.

I guess this is a ajax queuing problem, but `<a4j:queue ignoreDupResponses="true"/>` didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

In detail:

For the client-side validation I added the annotation

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$", message = "Bad email")
private String email;
```

in the validation bean.

For the ajax fall-back (server side) part I added the bean method

```
public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {

   ... // Check if email is already taken 

}
```

The tag looks like

```
<h:inputText  id="registerFullname" value="#{registerPanelBean.email}" validator="#{registerPanelBean.validateEmail}">
   <rich:validator event="keyup"  />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message for="registerFullname">
</rich:message>
```